# EntityFramework custom sql query on virtual property

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We use 6.1.2 EF and we have edmx generated from database.

We have POCO class like:

```
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

    public long CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

What I need to do, is insert new virtual property with custom sql query calling like:

```
public virtual int ProductsCount { get; set; }
```

which will return `select count(1) from dbo.Product where CatgoryID = ***`
Is it possible to define virtual property like this? I find some sql query definitions in .edmx xml file, so I hope, there can be defined mine too. What can I replace the *** with?

After all, my code should be called as simple as:

```
context
    .Category
    .Include(x => x.ProductsCount)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: If you just call `Products.Count()` on a Category instance it will execute the relevant SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Messing with the generated XML is genrally not a good idea. Any regeneration will override your code.

IMO, your property shall look like :

```
public int ProductCount { get { return Products.Count(); } }
```

And your request should be :

```
context.Category.Include(x => x.Products).ToList();
```

If loading the full products list might lead to problems, I would use a DB View ot the Category table with a computed column and then update my EF mapping to have this new entity inherit the Category entity.

Comment: Oh a view... I try to create a view, looking what will EF generate for me :)

Comment: The explicit `Include` is not necessary, and it can hurt performances if we are only interested in the number of elements and lazy loading is enabled. If the collection has not already been loaded, a call to `Count()` will be translated to a `SELECT COUNT` query (if it has already been loaded, then the number of elements is obviously already known.

Comment: @Riokmij : My bad... My last project did not permit lazy loading. I had to specify the includes.

Comment: @Riokmij This is not correct. A call to `ProductCount` will first load `Products` and then return the count. `Include` is the better option here if you know upfront you're going to address these counts.

Answer (score 0):

If Entity Framework had formula properties, like NHibernate, this could be a viable option. However, with Entity Framework you can't do this without breaking persistence ignorance and generating n + 1 queries.

- Persistence ignorance: entities are not supposed to have any reference to the data layer that created them. This is an important proposition that shouldn't be broken. Else you create a situation in which it is hard to track (and to predict) when and where queries will be executed. Moreover, it breaks the *single responsibility* principle.
- n + 1 anti pattern: other than NHibernate with formula properties, EF won't be able to integrate the embedded query in the query it executes to fetch `Category`s from the database (1). Each category will subsequently execute its own query (n).

The best way to do this is project the data to a view model (or DTO class, whichever name suits you best):

```
context.Categories.Select(c => new CategoryModel
{
    Name = c.Name,
    OtherProperty = c.OtherProperty,
    ProductsCount = c.Products.Count()
}
```

When it comes to projections you should always look at what **AutoMapper** can do for you. If you have this `CategoryModel` class you can define a mapping once (at application startup)...

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Catecory,CategoryModel>();
```

...and use it like so:

```
context.Categories.Project().To<CategoryModel>();
```

The nice thing of AutoMapper is that it parses a property like `ProductsCount` into a property in the source class, `Products`, and the operation working on it, `Count()`. This single line of code does exactly the same thing as the previous code snippet.

Side note: likewise, AutoMapper parses nested properties. A property `CategoryName` you might have in a `ProductModel` class (if Product-Category is n-1) would resolve to `product.Category.Name`.